# Return a new instance of child class from base class: circular reference

Tags: typescript

I want to create an Instance of a child in a static method of the base class like this:

```
class Baseclass {
    public static create(){
        const newInstance = new Childclass();
        return newInstance;
    }
}

class Childclass extends Baseclass {}

const anInstance = Baseclass.create();
```

this works as expected. But if I want to put each class into a separate file, I am getting

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

You can see an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iaprfj).
I think this is related to the imports which create some kind of circular reference. But since this works when both classes are defined in the same file, I only assume that it should work in some way when they are in separate files, also.

Answer (score 3):

As I found out on a [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20361) and on a related [github repository about the problem](https://github.com/ashleydavis/typescript-circular-class-dependency-problem), the solution is to use `index.ts` with

```
export { Baseclass } from './baseclass';
// NOTE: Putting this line first causes a problem.
export { Childclass } from './childclass';
```

then only reference to it instead of the files. see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bydbcl)

Comment: Generally it's not safe and depends on modular environment. This may work with Webpack. But I would expect it to fail with native ES modules (didn't check it yet).

Answer (score 0):

Putting `Baseclass` and `Childclass` into different modules creates circular reference between them that cannot be resolved with ES modules; `Baseclass` needs `Childclass` to be imported to be defined and vice versa.

The problem here is `Baseclass`. It isn't really base class because it refers to child class directly, while it shouldn't be aware of its descendants. If there should be factory method, it can reference `this` as class constructor in static method. If base classes isn't supposed to be used on its own, it can be abstract:

```
abstract class Baseclass {
    public static create(){
        return new this();
    }
}

class Childclass extends Baseclass {}
```

Comment: okey maybe i mixed up the terminology, feel free to edit. But for my case it is important to return an Instance of `Childclass` instead of `this`, i.e. `Baseclass`

Comment: @InsOp The only way to solve this is to fall back to CJS `require` instead of import because this way an import can be late AND synchronous import, e.g. `const Childclass = require('...').Childclass; const newInstance = new Childclass()`. This is a hack in TS because it's type unsafe. This is generally an antipattern in OOP. Parents shouldn't be aware of their children.  Why do you need that? Looks like XY problem to me.

Comment: I need that factory pattern for  creating Instances asynchronously. I load data from a database in the `Baseclass` and then decide which Instance of which decendant to give back in the `create` method. See my answer, I think I found a solution

Comment: This wasn't presented in the question. If you need them *asynchronously* then possibly your best bet is dynamic `import()`, it's evaluated lazily and doesn't create circular dependency. I'd consider that solution a hack since it relies on other mechanisms to resolve circular dependencies (https://github.com/ashleydavis/typescript-circular-class-dependency-problem falls back to `require`). I've just checked it with native ESM and they failed to resolve.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. is there a possibility that my solution gets deprecated?
did you check https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bydbcl ,too and it also failed to resolve?

Comment: Stackblitz uses SystemJS for modules. it doesn't use native modules so it's not representative. I've checked this setup with both Chrome and Node native modules. It works with Chrome implementation but fails to resolve in Node.